# Magento 2 option products of bundle are not showing in my orders magento core

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, bundled-product, magento-core

I need the Qty of bundle options that I have ordered.

I can see **getChildrenItems()** on getting the count it returns me 1, it doesn't include child products.

> Bundle/templates/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
>
> $items = array_merge([$parentItem], $parentItem->getChildrenItems());

renderer.phtml loads for both my orders and print order, For print I can see child product.

**My Order**

[image]

**Print Order**
[image]

How can i get the list of child products and the Qty ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your core module Sales Remove

```
Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Items.php
//$this->itemCollection->filterByParent(null);
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16434

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7e78060c166672fbbd069875812856856d6815f8

Comment: I can see bundle options in my orders now, But I am facing a issue with pagination, If a bundle products option goes to the 2nd page its renders as a simple product and not as bundle option But for print view i can get the outcome.